# Disable Google Chrome Sign In and Sync

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

Today, I came across [this blog post](https://blog.ideasynthesis.com/2018/09/24/Disable-Google-Chrome-Sign-In-and-Sync/):

> [As you might have heard](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2018/09/23/why-im-leaving-chrome/), [Chrome 69 automatically logs you into the browser when you log into any Google property](https://liliputing.com/2018/09/chrome-69-effectively-requires-you-to-stay-logged-in-if-you-want-to-use-any-google-services.html). As much as I might like Chrome (and Google), I was quite displeased by this particular change: I assume it was in the release notes (that probably a vanishingly small number of Chrome users read), but the rationale that's been given for the change doesn't really make sense, and in any case I really prefer not to have anything synced anywhere. It definitely (for me at least) violated the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): I can't speak for anyone else but I personally don't expect a routine software upgrade to suddenly start uploading passwords somewhere, or copying my passwords onto any random computer I happen to log into.
>
> As noted in the first article above, the Sync enabled/disabled UI was singularly confusing to me as to what the state of things are, and a careful search (well, about 1 minute) through the Chrome settings pages didn't really shed much more light on exactly how I could guarantee no data gets inadvertently synced. I set out to figure out how I could keep using Chrome but still feel relatively comfortable that Chrome Sync wasn't helpfully distributing my data. After a couple of hours running around I finally got it together thanks to https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3.
>
> For OSX, open a terminal window and run:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.google.Chrome SyncDisabled -bool true
> defaults write com.google.Chrome RestrictSigninToPattern -string ".*@example.com"
> ```

How can I do the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: A more useful way to present a quotation is to use copy/paste rather than an image. Most importantly, it is preferred that the source be provided.

Comment: @user535733 the same

Comment: Hmmm. On my Chrome 69, incognito browsing to Google sites does not seem to log me in to those sites. Perhaps the question could be clarified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `ungoogled-chrome` which is a modified version of Chrome/Chromium with all the Google spying removed:

https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium